# I'm trying to make a button in html that directs the user to another page. It's not a link it's API Piece

Tags: html, css, api, button

I've tried to follow tutorials to make the button, but it's not working. The button will appear and I can click on it but nothing happens.

```
{ < a href= "/schools/{{term['TermCode']}}" >
< p > {{ term['TermDescr'] }} < /p>
< /a > }
```

That is what  I want to turn into a button!!  but it's not working when I try to include the   tag. Help...`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed in a previous question:
[How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

I've found the form/submit format to be effective:

```
<form name="blah" action="link/i/want">
    <input type="submit" value="Go somewhere">
</form>
```

I had cross-browser issues with other means of doing this.